# React/Tailwind CSS: browser and web application versions render differently

Tags: css, reactjs, frontend, tailwind-css

I am using the latest version of React with the latest version of Tailwind CSS. When I open my design in the browser, it appears differently as shown in the image [Browser Version Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esGWU.jpg). However, when I install it as a web application, the design appears as shown in the image [WebApp Version Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgHg4.jpg).

Here is my code:

```
<div>
  <Link to="/dashboard">
    <FaHome className="text-2xl" />
  </Link>
</div>
<div ref={refTwo}>
  <FaSearch />
</div>
<div
  className={`border rounded-full p-2 ${
    props.mode === "white" ? "border-gray-200" : "border-gray-500"
  }`}>
  <Link to="/dashboard/add-invoices">
    <FaPlus />
  </Link>
</div>
<div>
  <div
    className="cursor-pointer"
    onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
    ref={refOne}>
    <div className="h-9 w-9 rounded-full flex items-center justify-center z-10 -mr-2">
      <img src={userData.image} alt="img" className="rounded-full" />
    </div>
    <div>
      {open && (
        <ul
          className={`${
            props.mode === "white" ? "bg-white" : "bg-[#1a1a1a]"
          } p-2 w-44 shadow-xl border-2 absolute -mt-[25rem] rounded -ml-16 xl:-ml-44 transition-all duration-300 text-gray-500 z-[99999]`}>
          <li className="text-sm my-3">
            Welcome {userData.firstName()}
          </li>
          {Menus1.map((menuA, pos) => (
            <li
              key={pos}
              className={`p-2 cursor-pointer text-sm rounded hover:text-white bg-gradient-to-r hover:from-[#09C6F9] hover:to-[#045DE9] flex my-1 items-center`}>
              <div className="mr-3">{menuA.icon}</div>
              <Link
                to={menuA.link}
                onClick={props.open ? null : props.handleChange}>
                {" "}
                {menuA.title}
              </Link>
            </li>
          ))}
          <li className="my-2">
            <hr />
          </li>
          {Menus2.map((menuB, sos) => (
            <li
              key={sos}
              className={`p-2 cursor-pointer text-sm rounded my-1 hover:text-white bg-gradient-to-r hover:from-[#09C6F9] hover:to-[#045DE9] flex items-center ${
                menuB.color ? "text-red-600" : ""
              }`}>
              <div className="mr-3">{menuB.icon}</div>
              <button onClick={() => handleSubmit(menuB.title)}>
                {" "}
                {menuB.title}
              </button>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      )}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div className="cursor-pointer text-2xl">
  {props.open === true ? (
    <HiMenuAlt1 onClick={props.handleChange} />
  ) : (
    <HiMenuAlt1 className="rotate-180" onClick={props.handleChange} />
  )}
</div>
</div>
```

I am expecting both the browser and web app designs to look the same.

Comment: I can't spot any difference, apart from the browsers address bar, of course.

Comment: @kca Please check the below of menu bar. There is a blank space in web app image.